# How to create a variable with rolling window conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I would like to create a variable a binary variable that takes 1 if there is an increase of the score of at least 2 points within a 3 year time window. That is, in the following example, I'd like to consider the period 1950-1952, assign the value 1 over this entire window if there is at least one improvement between two years greater than or equal to two, then move on to the period 1953-1955.

```
data = {
    'year': [1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958],
    'teamcode': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'teamname': ['Team 1'] * 9,
    'score': [0, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, -10, -10, -10]
}
```

I've failed with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['differences'] = df['e_polity2'].diff()

df['binary_var'] = (df['differences'] >= 2).astype(int)

df['binary_var'] = df['binary_var'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).max()

df['binary_var'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to perform everything with a `groupby` and on the reversed Series for the rolling part:

```
s = df.groupby(['teamcode', 'teamname'])['score'].diff().gt(2)
df['binary_var'] = (s[::-1].groupby([df['teamcode'], df['teamname']])
                    .rolling(3, min_periods=1).max().droplevel([0,1])
                   )
```

Output:

```
   year  teamcode teamname  score  binary_var
0  1950         4   Team 1      0         1.0
1  1951         4   Team 1      1         1.0
2  1952         4   Team 1      5         1.0
3  1953         4   Team 1      5         0.0
4  1954         4   Team 1      5         0.0
5  1955         4   Team 1      6         0.0
6  1956         4   Team 1    -10         0.0
7  1957         4   Team 1    -10         0.0
8  1958         4   Team 1    -10         0.0
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. However, when I try this code with other data values, such as :'score': [0, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 12, -10]; the output is not satisfying. To be clear, I want to identify the distincts 3 year window periods when there is at least one year to year increase of the score of at least 2 points.

Comment: @redha the logic is unclear then, I believe this is what the code is doing.